# Mysql montly sum between two years?

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

I'm getting the records of weeks from specific year.

```
   SELECT ....
      SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(readdate) = 201602, readamount, 0)) AS "201601w",
      SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(readdate) = 201701, readamount, 0)) AS "201701w" 
    FROM ...
```

How can I get that monthly between 2 or 3 year?

For example:

```
   SELECT ....
      SUM(IF(YEARMONTH(readdate) = 201602(Feb), readamount, 0)) AS "201601m",
      SUM(IF(YEARMONTH(readdate) = 201701(Jan), readamount, 0)) AS "201701m" 
    FROM ...
```

My full query:

```
SELECT wirters.writer,
SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(readdate) = 201602, read, 0)) AS "201601",
SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(readdate) = 201701, read, 0)) AS "201701" 
FROM writers
LEFT JOIN reads ON wirters.writer_id = reads.writer_id   
GROUP BY wirters.writer
```

Output I need

```
+---------------+---------+---------+
| writer        | 2016Feb | 2017Jan | 
+---------------+---------+---------+
| George Orwell |    13   |   663   |
| Dan Brown     |    22   |   32    |
+---------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Look into the basic concept of GROUPing records BY specified criteria.

Comment: You should show us your full query, but your current approach seems on the right track; you can use conditional aggregation to sum over a given period of time.

Comment: I do not really understand what you are after. But if you want a dynamic pivot table with month between two dates being the columns, then there are solution to this on SO.

Comment: I'm not sure to get correct result if use where condition. WHERE YEAR(readdate) BETWEEN 2016 AND 2017

Comment: Show us some sample data, expected outcome based on sample data, your current query and the results it produces.

Comment: Im so sorry writing mistake. I update my question.

Comment: You're doing two things here: *summarizing by month*, and *pivoting* the result.  It may help you to approach your problem that way.